# tinymce react plugin registration does not work

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tinymce, wysiwyg

Was trying to register a custom plugin in tinymce but ever attempt failed.

- Created a plugin using yoman generator build it and reference in the project
- Created a plugin using yoman generator directly reference in the project without building
- Also tried the below approach is still doesn't work
- 

```
import { FC, RefObject, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import { plugins, toolbar, quickBarsInsertToolbar } from './config';
import tinymce, { Editor as TinyMCEEditor, PluginManager } from 'tinymce';
import './index.css'
// import '../../plugins/dropdown-plugin/dist/dropdown-plugin/plugin.min.js';



const TinymceEditor: FC = () => {
    const editorRef = useRef<TinyMCEEditor | null>(null);
    const log = () => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
            console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
        }
    };


    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        tinymce.PluginManager.add("dropdown-plugin", function (n, t) { n.ui.registry.addButton("dropdown-plugin", { text: "dropdown-plugin button", onAction: function () { n.setContent("<p>content added from dropdown-plugin</p>") } }) })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div
            className='tinymce_editor'
        >
            <Editor
                onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
                init={{
                    height: 500,
                    plugins:['dropdown-plugin'],
                    toolbar:'dropdown-plugin'
                }}
            />
            <button onClick={log}>Log editor content</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TinymceEditor;
```

Gives this error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally Working now

```
import { FC, useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import { plugins, toolbar, quickBarsInsertToolbar } from './config';
import { Editor as TinyMCEEditor } from 'tinymce';
import './index.css'
import { registerPlugins } from './plugin/register-plugins';




const TinymceEditor: FC = () => {
    const editorRef = useRef<TinyMCEEditor | null>(null);
    const log = () => {
        if (editorRef.current) {
            console.log(editorRef.current.getContent());
        }
    };


    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        registerPlugins()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div
            className='tinymce_editor'
        >
            <Editor
                onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
                init={{
                    height: 500,
                    plugins: plugins,
                    quickbars_insert_toolbar: quickBarsInsertToolbar,
                    toolbar: toolbar

                }}
            />
            <button onClick={log}>Log editor content</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TinymceEditor;
```

```
import { customQuickBarButton } from './customQuickBarButton';
import tinymce from 'tinymce';
import { customToolBarButtonMenu } from './customToolBarButtonMenu';

export const registerPlugins = () => {
  tinymce.PluginManager.add(
    'custom-quickbar-button-plugin',
    customQuickBarButton
  );
  tinymce.PluginManager.add(
    'custom-toolbar-button-menu-plugin',
    customToolBarButtonMenu
  );
};
```

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Editor } from 'tinymce';

export const customToolBarButtonMenu = (editor: Editor) => {
  editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('custom-toolbar-button-menu-plugin', {
    text: 'Custom Menu',
    icon: 'language',
    fetch: callback => {
      var items = [
        {
          type: 'menuitem',
          text: 'Menu Item 1',
          icon: 'arrow-right',
          onAction: () => {
            editor.insertContent('&nbsp; <em>You clicked menu item 1!</em> ');
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'menuitem',
          text: 'Menu Item 2',
          icon: 'user',
          onAction: () => {
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            ReactDOM.render(
              <div>
                <span>Signature with image</span>
                <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/532/200/200.jpg?hmac=PPwpqfjXOagQmhd_K7H4NXyA4B6svToDi1IbkDW2Eos" />
              </div>,
              div
            );
            editor.selection.setNode(div);

          },
        },
      ];
      callback(items as any);
    },
  });
};
```